# jqGrid - how to pass both the boolean checked state value and the actual unique value to a checkbox in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JSP page with multiple instances of a jqGrid. One column of that grid has checkbox representing if the row is selected or not. I need to have a normal HTML like checkbox in jqGrid - the one that has both a checked/unchecked boolean state and the actual unique value like: 
 `<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="checked" />`

In the jqGrid I am facing a limitation wherein I can only pass one value to the checkbox. In the colModel of jqGrid I have this:

```
colModel:[
    {name:'assign', index:'assign', width:200, editable:true, edittype:'checkbox', formatter:"checkbox", formatoptions:{disabled : false}}
    ]
```

In passing the data to my jqGrid I have this kind of data:

```
var mydata = [
              {assign:"${assignBool}"}
           ];
```

However the value being set in colModel [] "assign" could either be the boolean value
determining if checkbox is checked or not OR it could be the actual value we want to set for the checkbox to determine which checkbox was checked.

While passing boolean value I could get the checkboxes checked correctly in the display but couldn't get the values (the unique identifying values).

While passing the actual unique values to "assign" all the checkboxes were showing the incorrect default checked state for all the checkboxes.

I could not determine how to pass both the checked state boolean and the actual unique value of checkbox to the "assign" row in jqGrid.

I want to be able to traverse through the whole page using the code below and get the actual unique values of all the checkboxes:

```
$("#editBtn").click(function() {
    var val = [];
    var checkedNames = '';
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(index) {
        val[index] = $(this).val() + ',';
        checkedNames += val[index];
        }
    );  
    alert("Checked check box values: " + checkedNames);
});
```

If I pass the boolean checked state to the "assign" above, all I am getting in the checkedNames variable is a list of True/False or Yes/No values and not the actual values.

Has anyone else faced similar problem or does anyone have a solution to this issue? To me it seems like a limitation of jqGrid or maybe I am not aware of such a functionality in jqGrid. Any help in this regard would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I often do with jqGrid to manage custom behavior is to pass the HTML I want to appear to the colModel as text.  So instead of using the `edit` properties you've listed above, just send the HTML as text in your JSON response from the server.

jqGrid will render this as HTML and then you can manage the behavior with jQuery (which it looks like you're familiar with).

**UPDATE**
For example, I wanted to integrate [jQuery Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/) into my grid, so in my controller on my server (I'm using ASP.NET MVC), I return:

```
return Json(new
{
    total = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)data.Count / rows),
    page = 1,
    records = data.Count,
    rows = (from item in data
            select new
             {
                 id = "GR" + data.IndexOf(item),
                 cell = new object[] 
                 { 
                     item.Name,
                     "<span class=\"inlinesparkline\" values=\"" + item.SparklineData + "\"></span>"
                 }
             }).ToArray()
        });
```

In my jqGrid, this column is in the colModel as text:

```
...
colModel: [
    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name' },
    { name: 'Sparkline', index: 'Sparkline', classes: 'sparkcell' }
],
...
```

Now in my gridComplete, I can use jQuery to do whatever I need using the `.sparkcell` selector:

```
...
gridComplete: function () {
    $('.sparkcell').sparkline();
},
...
```

Comment: Paul, thanks for the advice. Could you give a snippet of a code wherein you do as mentioned? I got the overall concept but I am not sure how to actually implement that.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Seems like it should work. I will try to customize a similar solution to my requirements and see if it works for me.